# How can I use the addonblur setting on the Mootools TextBoxList?

Tags: javascript, mootools, textboxlist

I am using [Mootools TextBoxList](http://devthought.com/projects/mootools/textboxlist) for a project. I was attempting to set the addonblur option so new tags entered would automatically be added to the list when the text box looses focus. However, I am unable to determine the correct syntax for how to set this.

I read the documentation several times and tried different things, but couldn’t get it.
My current initialization looks like this:

```
window.addEvent('load', function () {
var t = new TextboxList('txtAttributes', {unique: true, plugins: {autocomplete: {
     minLength: 3,
     queryRemote: true,
     remote: {url: 'tagssuggest'}
}}});
```

How can I modify this to include `addonblur: true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var t = new TextboxList('txtAttributes', {
  bitsOptions: {
    unique: true,
    editable: {
      addOnBlur: true
    },
    plugins: {
      autocomplete: {
        minLength: 3,
        queryRemote: true,
        remote: {url: 'tagssuggest'}
      }
    }
  }
});
```